# Django compressor not converting images to data URIs

Tags: css, django, data-uri, django-compressor

I'm having issues setting up replacing of URLs with data URIs with django compressor. Here are relevant settings:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'foo', 'bar'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'foo', 'baz'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = os.environ.get('STATIC_FILE_URL', '/static/')

CSS_INCLUDE_PATHS = '.:{foo}'.format(growth=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'foo'))
LESSC_COMMAND = 'node_modules/.bin/lessc {include_paths} {{infile}} {{outfile}} --autoprefix="> 1%"'.format(
    include_paths="--include-path='{paths}'".format(paths=CSS_INCLUDE_PATHS)
)

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', LESSC_COMMAND),
    ('text/javascript', 'node_modules/.bin/rollup {infile} -c rollup.config.js --output {outfile}'),
)

COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS = [
    'compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter',
    'compressor.filters.datauri.CssDataUriFilter',
]

# 5KB limit
COMPRESS_DATA_URI_MAX_SIZE = 5 * 1024

# Explicitly enabled so it works in DEBUG mode as well
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
```

However, I'm still seeing non-data URLs in generated CSS for images (and there are some images less than 5KB in size for sure).

What am I missing?

Edit: abridged template and styles

Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    {% load compress %}
    {% load static from staticfiles %}

    {% include "foo/head-base.html" %}

    {% compress css %}
    <link type="text/less" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'static/styles/style.less' %}" />
    {% endcompress %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- loading some templates here -->
    {% compress js %}
    <script src="{% static 'foo/scripts/script.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endcompress %}
```

Style

```
// Define the root path.
@static_root: '/static';

// some styles here

// and a bunch of imports near the end
@import "foo";
@import "bar";
// ...etc
```

Comment: can you show the template and css file in question?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: It's probably related to this -> https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/278

Comment: can you add the code where some image is included that is not encoded properly?